# LaCie 2big RAID linux support

Tags: hard-disk, raid, external-hdd

I have a [LaCie 2big](https://www.lacie.com/as/en/products/big/2big/) in RAID 1 on their side. There is no official Linux support available. Is there a way to check the drives and raid health under Linux via third-party tools?